# Como referenciar dos tablas en un campo

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sequelize

me pueden ayudar?

Estoy tratando de crear a través del ORM Sequelize y Node.js un modelo de base de datos relacional en MySQL que me permita guardar un registro de transacción que contendrá el origen y el destino del dinero. Tengo la tabla ingresos (que siempre sera un origen), también tengo la tabla gastos (que siempre sera un destino) pero quiero que el destino pueda ser un gasto u otro ingreso. Estaba pensando en usar llaves foráneas pero no puedo asociar las dos tablas al mismo campo de destino. Que puedo hacer?
La idea es tener algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: le puedes agregar un campo id para hacer referencia a la que deses en diferentes tablas!

Comment: Pero en la tabla transacciones como asocio las otras dos tablas en el campo destino con el ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso que intentas hacer ya se inventó hace miles de años, se llama *contabilidad*. Lo que revolucionó el sistema fue el *doble apunte contable* o *partida doble*, en el siglo XV: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partida_doble Échale un vistazo y verás que es mucho más flexible y versátil que la solución que propones.

Para tu caso concreto, únicamente necesitarás una estructura como ésta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puedes generar a partir de estas instrucciones:

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
  id_cuenta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cuenta varchar(31),
  ingreso bool,
  activo bool
  );
CREATE TABLE apuntes(
  id_apunte int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha datetime,
  id_debe int,
  id_haber int,
  debe float,
  haber float,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_debe) REFERENCES cuentas(id_cuenta),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_haber) REFERENCES cuentas(id_cuenta)
  );
INSERT INTO cuentas (cuenta,ingreso,activo) VALUES
  ('Salario',1,0),
  ('Ahorro 1',NULL,1),
  ('Ahorro 2',NULL,1),
  ('Hipoteca',0,1),
  ('Sevicios',0,1),
  ('Impuestos',0,1);
INSERT INTO apuntes (fecha, id_debe, id_haber, debe, haber) VALUES
  (NOW(),2,1,100,100),
  (NOW(),3,1,100,100),
  (NOW(),4,2,50,50),
  (NOW(),6,2,5,5),
  (NOW(),4,3,50,50);
```

Para obtener el *Libro Diario* puedes usar esta consulta:

```
SELECT fecha,debe,c_debe,c_haber,haber
  FROM apuntes
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_cuenta id_debe,cuenta c_debe
      FROM cuentas
  ) debe USING(id_debe)
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_cuenta id_haber,cuenta c_haber
      FROM cuentas
  ) haber USING(id_haber)
  ORDER BY fecha;

+---------------------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| fecha               | debe | c_debe    | c_haber  | haber |
+---------------------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| 2022-09-10 09:03:52 |  100 | Ahorro 1  | Salario  |   100 |
| 2022-09-10 09:03:52 |  100 | Ahorro 2  | Salario  |   100 |
| 2022-09-10 09:03:52 |   50 | Hipoteca  | Ahorro 1 |    50 |
| 2022-09-10 09:03:52 |    5 | Impuestos | Ahorro 1 |     5 |
| 2022-09-10 09:03:52 |   50 | Hipoteca  | Ahorro 2 |    50 |
+---------------------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

O esta otra para otra para el *Libro Mayor* de la cuenta `Salario` con `id_cuenta=1`:

```
SELECT fecha,debe,c_debe,c_haber,haber
  FROM apuntes
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_cuenta id_debe,cuenta c_debe
      FROM cuentas
  ) debe USING(id_debe)
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_cuenta id_haber,cuenta c_haber
      FROM cuentas
  ) haber USING(id_haber)
  WHERE id_debe=1 OR id_haber=1
  ORDER BY fecha;

+---------------------+------+----------+---------+-------+
| fecha               | debe | c_debe   | c_haber | haber |
+---------------------+------+----------+---------+-------+
| 2022-09-10 09:03:52 |  100 | Ahorro 1 | Salario |   100 |
| 2022-09-10 09:03:52 |  100 | Ahorro 2 | Salario |   100 |
+---------------------+------+----------+---------+-------+
```

Y, los saldos de las diferentes cuentas, que es lo que supongo que más te interese, se pueden calcular de esta forma:

```
SELECT *,(IFNULL(debe,0)-IFNULL(haber,0))*IF(activo,1,-1) saldo
  FROM cuentas LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_debe id_cuenta,SUM(debe) debe
      FROM apuntes
      GROUP BY 1
  ) debe USING(id_cuenta)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_haber id_cuenta,SUM(haber) haber
      FROM apuntes
      GROUP BY 1
  ) haber USING(id_cuenta);

+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+------+-------+-------+
| id_cuenta | cuenta    | ingreso | activo | debe | haber | saldo |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+------+-------+-------+
|         1 | Salario   |       1 |      0 | NULL |   200 |   200 |
|         2 | Ahorro 1  |    NULL |      1 |  100 |    55 |    45 |
|         3 | Ahorro 2  |    NULL |      1 |  100 |    50 |    50 |
|         4 | Hipoteca  |       0 |      1 |  100 |  NULL |   100 |
|         5 | Sevicios  |       0 |      1 | NULL |  NULL |     0 |
|         6 | Impuestos |       0 |      1 |    5 |  NULL |     5 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+------+-------+-------+
```

En cuanto te familiarices con lo que es un *activo*, un *pasivo*, un *gasto* y un *ingreso*, con consultas similares podrás calcular el *saldo* de las *cuentas contables*, obtener *balances*, *cuentas de resultados* y todo lo que necesites.